# Navigation link is not loading due to 403 error while loading JS file

Tags: javascript

There are different financial institutions to which we are providing a solution. For some of the FIs all the JS files are loading fine but for few FIs it is throwing below error,

GET https://lptag.liveperson.net/tag/tag.js?site=84401721 net::ERR_ABORTED 403

and functionality is failing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you serve your page? What is the query param doing `site==84401721`? I think there is logic around it

Comment: 84401721 is the account id which is used by application to establish the connection with Admin for end user chatting facility.

Comment: I think that is where the problem is. It is throwing forbidden for that input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a whitelist setting on the Admin(client who was serving the js) and after removing the whitelist restriction js is loading fine.